# What happened to Gwen in "The Amazing Spider-Man 2"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-amazing-spider-man-2

I remember the scene in *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* where Gwen falls from the clock tower and Spider-Man uses his web to catch her before she touches the ground, and he did catch her.

But I still don't understand what exactly she died from.

Comment: Her neck snapped. She decelerated too abruptly, with her torso held by Spidey's web, that her neck couldn't possibly take that force.

Comment: ^^ Untrue.  Well, it may be partially true.

Comment: Absolutely...you can hear the snap! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6if4GOyWqs

Comment: She doesn't snap her neck, she hits the floor with her head. If you don't believe me, you can look at this [freeze frame](https://image.prntscr.com/image/Ot0wTSxKTKaCWubcQVnkMQ.png)

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, if it was an internal decapitation her spine would probably be sticking out of her neck after a tv:0 deceleration..

Comment: ["Before Gwen hits the ground Peter's web reaches her and stops the fall. Unfortunately, the web stretches which caused Gwen to hit her head on the floor, which causes her to die instantly."](http://amazingspiderman.wikia.com/wiki/Gwen_Stacy)

Comment: @GhotiandChips, that freeze frame is GNARLY! It is clearly a dummy but still, the shape and position of head vs the rest of the body gives me the heebie-jeebies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm at work so I can't upload images due to internal security, but if you freeze-frame the exact moment the web that caught her pulls taut, you can see she clearly hit the ground.  Her head hits the ground and so do her hands.

So, while it's possible her neck snapped, it's also pretty clear that part of her body lands with a thud.

Try to freeze this video at the 51 second mark and you'll see it.

Comment: You're right (and the commentors claiming she snaps her neck are wrong). I took a [freeze frame](https://image.prntscr.com/image/Ot0wTSxKTKaCWubcQVnkMQ.png) of the moment it happens. Mind you, it's possible she snapped her neck, too, but it's not a completely accurate answer.

Comment: This is right. I conflated the film with the source comic (_The Amazing Spider-Man_ #21), [in which her neck snaps](https://www.scienceabc.com/pure-sciences/science-behind-the-death-of-gwen-stacy-could-spiderman-have-saved-her.html).